# Create Persistent volume using command line (without using any file)

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I want to create PV using the `kubectl` command line, Is it possible in Kubernetes or not. If it is possible then how?

Comment: You can create whatever resource you like with `kubectl` using `Here documents`. The kubectl [cheat sheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/)  has examples how to apply them.

Comment: This document doesn't contain any command to create PV.  Can u provide a correct link @Ralf

Comment: I have asked to create PV without creating any file just using a command, read the question carefully and don't downvote if u don't know answer @Ralf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For infrastructure, it has become a good practice to use *declarative* files to provision new infrastructure. Therefore an imperative variant only using `kubectl` commands for creating [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) has not been implemented.

Persistent Volumes are typically created in one of two ways:

- Automatically created by a [dynamic volume provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/) service. What service is used depends on your environment, e.g. on-prem or a cloud provider like Google Cloud Platform or Amazon Web Services.
- In some cases, created using `kubectl` and yaml manifests, typically by an operator.